# What branch of analysis deals most with sequences and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, soft-question

I'm really interested in sequences and series (mainly series). What kind of math branch should I look more into? I understand that sequences and series mostly point toward analysis, but what sub-branch of analysis would I most enjoy?

For the sake of context, I am a senior in high school and I've taken single variable and multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and elementary differential equations.

I'm currently taking an introductory course on real analysis at a local university.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: Did you check out Knopp's books?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely true that sequences and series are the province of analysis. Generating functions take the form of discrete infinite sums and series and they are important tools in combinatorics and algebra. That being said, the study of sequences and series are **mostly** in analysis.

You should be warned,though,that as tools in real analysis and calculus, infinite series have largely been supplanted by direct numerical approximation methods.I'm extremely troubled by this drift because I think they are extraordinarily powerful tools in analysis-expressing functions locally as power series in a radius of convergence is very illuminating in "modeling" a function's behavior.But mathematicians-particularly numerical analysts-see infinite series as archaic tools for solving differential equations and look to rely on more rapidly convergent methods of approximation.

In complex analysis, however, where functions have the much stronger conditions of holomorphicity, infinite series and sequences still play an enormously important role to not only quantify analyticity, but to define the properties of contour integrals where singularities exist along paths. The main tool for this is Laurent series. I think you'll find a great deal of fascinating material to mine in complex analysis along these lines, usually presented in graduate complex analysis.

Comment: I see my fan club is at it again.

Comment: That's why I said "sequences and series mostly point toward analysis" in my original question. I too see series as powerful tools. A very basic example from single variable calculus being that approximating transcendental functions as infinite series can simplify integration (and differentiation). So in reference to someone else's answer: how would you compare harmonic analysis to complex analysis in terms of studying series?

Comment: Well,in classical harmonic analysis,the key objects are Fourier series and transforms,which are a specific kind of infinite series which play a major role in both mathematics and physics. In a nutshell, all sufficiently smooth functions within a radius of convergence can be represented by an infinite series made up entirely of sine and cosine functions.But once you get past this basic idea, the role of infinite series nearly vanishes in harmonic analysis;the key idea then becomes that of the REPRESENTATION of the function on it's domain,which becomes generalized far beyond real Fourier series.

Comment: hmm interesting. Well that leads to another question then: is there still much research to be done on series? Or, for the most part, have we pretty much figured them out?

Comment: With the exception of some unique series of functions and thier resulting spaces in functional analysis,I think the theory of infinite series was more or less estabilished by the end of the 19th century. User,here's my advice to you: Mathematics builds vertically from a foundation dating back to ancient times and floors are built on top of the old results.YOU HAVE TO LEARN THE CURRENT BRANCHES OF MATHEMATICS BEFORE EVEN BEGINNING TO THINK OF RESEARCH. I remember a story my mentor Nick Metas told me about a fellow graduate student he knew at MIT,who was a gifted undergraduate.(continued)

Comment: (continued) Then as a graduate student,he refused to study basic algebra,analysis and topology and would only read currently published papers and go to oral lectures.This was despite the fact he had glaring holes in his background knowledge-no Sylow theory, no noncommutative ring theory,no measure theory,etc. "I refuse to learn dusty dead mathematics-only LIVING mathematics!" He ultimately flunked out and Nick never heard of him again.Learn the foundations first. Then start seeing what floors you can build yourself.

Comment: Ah,my fan club.So nice to be apprieciated.

Answer (score 1):

Wilf's book *generatingfunctionolgy*, available [freely online](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), leads off with a quick list of the ways infinite series are used in combinatorics (where they are called generating functions); he immediately follows this up with some nice examples. The first time one encounters this sort of thing, it seems like magic. Glance through the table of contents and the first chapter to get the flavor.

The free online article by Carl Offner ["A Little Harmonic Analysis"](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/files/harm_an.pdf) gives a nice introduction to the theory of Fourier series. To quote from his webpage:

> As I was writing this up, I got interested in some historical questions. At the end of the paper I include a historical sketch that includes my views on two controversial topics:

- Did Abel prove "Abel's theorem" on the convergence of power series? (Yes, he did.)
- Did Dirichlet really come up with the modern definition of function? (I think it's quite reasonable to say that he did.)

> and also my thoughts on a question that I have not seen dealt with seriously before:

- Why was Fejér's theorem such a sensation, since the essential results had been known for many years?

You might enjoy learning about $p$-adics, important in number theory, where the rationals are completed using a different metric than the usual one; in the 2-adics, for example, $1+2+4+\ldots 2^n+\ldots$ converges just fine.

Also a little off the beaten track (at the undergrad level, at least), the theory of divergent series contains many gems; the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) provides a nice starting point.

Finally, let me echo another poster: series really shine in complex analysis. The sooner any student encounters this branch of math, the better. In 300 years it has lost none of its lustre.